# CentOS 7 + Nginx + Google Compute Engine (permission forbidden error)

Tags: nginx, centos7

I'm fairly new to Nginx. I configured Nginx to use virtualhosts (server blocks) and restarted nginx but I am getting two errors that make no sense to me...

This is what my vhost server block looks like

```
server {
listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server;

root /custom/path/to/public_html;
index index.html index.htm index.php;
server_name _;
#access_log /custom/path/to/log/oq.default.access.log combined buffer=1024k;
#error_log /custom/path/to/log/oq.default.error.log;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}

error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
    root   html;
}
```

}

**Error number #1:**
***prior to commenting out*** the access_log line, nginx would fail to start, with the following error `2017/01/23 02:10:23 [emerg] 26984#0: open() "/custom/path/to/log/oq.default.access.log" failed (13: Permission denied)`

**Error number #2:**
after commenting out the access_log line, restart nginx (successfully) and that's when I get error 403 Forbidden on my site, when I go to the error log what it shows me

`2017/01/23 11:32:10 [error] 5812#0: *3 "/custom/path/to/public_html/index.html" is forbidden (13: Permission denied), client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"`

I set 777 to **BOTH** "public_html" and "log" folders and I change the owner to "nginx:nginx" and restart nginx and still the same errors still comes out

What am I missing?

Comment: Here is another clue --

if I move my index.html page to /usr/share/nginx/html (adjusting my conf file to the new root), restart nginx and reload my page -- everything works... ...but if I leave my custom path: /my/custom/path/public_html (adjusting my conf file to this root), restart nginx and reload my page -- it breaks with Permission denied errors...

both paths have the same exact permissions -- UGH!!

Comment: could this be an issue caused by SELinux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's SELinux:

```
grep nginx /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow -m nginx > nginx.te
cat nginx.te
grep nginx /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow -M nginx
semodule -i nginx.pp
```

Comment: SELinux was indeed the problem, I disabled it and had to reboot the box before everything worked

Comment: Thank you a lot, I want to say "f**k SELinux and GC", it took me about 2 hours to fix it. Things worked well in the old host, I just moved them to new one, then it broke.